# SQL - How to create a trigger involving 2 separate tables?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Create an INSERT trigger called checkPub  on the '**publishers**' table to add a row into the '**pub_info**' table
1) when a row is inserted into the 'publishers' table with the values of the pub_id inserted into the publishers table,
2) NULL in the logo column, and
3) the text 'Newbie' in the pr_info column.
4) In addition, print a message stating the pub_id along with '9991 Inserted into 'pub_info' table'.

```
INSERT INTO publishers( pub_id, pub_name, city, country )
VALUES( '9905', 'New Publisher', 'Vancouver', 'Canada' );

CREATE TRIGGER checkPub
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON 
(Publishers P JOIN pub_info PI
  ON   
P.pub_id = PI.pub_id)

FOR EACH ROW
```

Not sure how to write the conditions after this.

Comment: Triggers do NOT first on multiple tables. A trigger is like an event in OOP. It sounds like you need an insert statement that will insert default values and the foreign key to pub_info when a row is inserted into Publishers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any kind of looping here. You simply need a basic insert statement. Here is an example of the entire trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkPub ON Publishers after INSERT AS
    set nocount on;

    insert pub_info
    (
        pub_id
        , logo
        , pr_info
    )
    select i.pub_id
        , null
        , 'Newbie'
    from inserted i;
```

Since this has the look of homework I will let you figure out the last requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.